# assigning numbers to categorical variables in r

Tags: r

I have uploaded `csv` file in *R* using `import`. File contains 2 columns with Labels and corresponding text/description to the labels which is extracted from different news papers. It has more then 2k rows and labels get repeated. The labels are in textual form.

I need to map these to numerical values (business, entertainment, politics, sport, tech)  (0,1,2,3,4) after I upload the file. Can anybody please help me on this. I am very new *R* programming

Comment: Perhaps `as.factor`? I am not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your categories are of type character, you can use the `factor()` function to enumerate them, and subtract 1 to have it start at zero.

```
df <- data.frame( category = c("business", "entertainment", "business", "sport"), 
                  descr    = c("one", "two", "three", "four") )
df$number <- as.numeric( factor(df$category) ) -1
```

This results in:

```
       category descr number
1      business   one      0
2 entertainment   two      1
3      business three      0
4         sport  four      2
```

Comment: thanks.I will be more clear on the question.My csv file data is something like 
col1                    col2
entertainment   'Comeback' show for Friends star Friends play lead role..
politics                  from the Daily Telegraph said he would contest.....
like 2k plus rows repeating entertainment,politics,sports etc.I have imported the file in dummy
dummy <- read.csv("filepath")
Inside file 'dummy' I need to assign  numerical values (business, entertainment, politics, sport, tech)  (0,1,2,3,4) so I can plot a graph .